# Why is copy constructor called so late in function call?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, copy

In short, inside a function template, `Foo`, that is called by `main`, takes a universal reference and uses a field of supposedly local variable of `Foo`, it seems like the input parameter's (a reference to the local variable of `main`) fields are used when the field of "supposedly local variable of `Foo`" was referred.

My English skills are not too great to summarize my problem in a short paragraph first. Let me start with offering some backgrounds first.

I have a class that implements all five constructors intentionally wrongly:

```
class X {
public:
  X(const std::string& s) : s_(s) {
    std::cout << "X(const std::string&)" << std::endl;
  }
  X() {
    std::cout << "X()" << std::endl;
  }

  X(const X& x) : s_{"copy_con_val"} {
    std::cout << "X(const X&)" << std::endl;
  }

  X(X&& x) : s_{"move_con_val"} {
    std::cout << "X(X&&)" << std::endl;
  }

  X& operator=(const X& x)  {
    s_ = "copy_assign_val";
    std::cout << "X& operator=(const X&)" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }

  X& operator=(X&& x) {
    s_ = "move_assign_val";
    std::cout << "X& operator=(X&&)" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }

  std::string s_;
};
```

Please note that they are not using `s_` from the source. I have a function template, `Foo`:

```
template <typename T>
T Foo(T&& t) {
  T out{std::forward<T>(t)};
  std::cout << "out = " << out.s_ << std::endl;
  return out;
}
```

Then, I have the caller, `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])
{
  X x("name");
  // Expecting Foo to print "copy_con_value"
  auto y = Foo(x);
  std::cout << "all done: y = " << y.s_ << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output was different from what I expected, especially in the second line:

```
X(const std::string&)
out = name
X(const X&)
all done: y = copy_con_val
```

My understanding is, given the five constructors (let alone `X(const string&)`), the universal reference would become `const X&`. With regard to the return value optimization, the memory buffer for `out` is allocated in `main`. Especially, in this case, the memory buffer of `out` is the same as the memory buffer of `y`, the local variable of `main` that the return value is assigned to. The initialization would be effectively as follows:

```
// within Foo()'s scope
X main::y{static_cast<const X&>(main::x)};
X& out = main::y
```

Thus, when we use `out` within the scope of `Foo`, I believed the value of `out.s_` belongs to the new object, not to the source (i.e. `x`). I believed `copy_con_value` should be printed.

However, it looks like `out` within the `Foo` function is the reference to `x` in `main`. It looks as if the `copy construction` is delayed as far as it could go. Only after returning to `main`, the code needs both `x` and `y` there, and at least by then, an effective copy construction for `y` should happen. The very last moment, if we do not consider the side effect of copy constructor, might be when the return value is assigned to `y`.

Interestingly, if I change the function template, `Foo`, to a regular function `Bar` that takes `const X&` and does the same thing, then, it prints the `copy_con_val` out:

```
X Bar(const X& x) {
  X out{x};
  std::cout << "out = " << out.s_ << std::endl;
  return out;
}
```

Are these behaviors expected, which I guess it is? If it is expected, how should I understand the differences?

Comment: Why do you expect the universal reference to be `const X&` and not `X&`? I know you don't have an `X::X(X&)` constructor, but that doesn't affect what the universal reference type actually is.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, now I understood where I was lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```cpp
template <typename T>
T Foo(T&& t) {
  T out{std::forward<T>(t)};
  std::cout << "out = " << out.s_ << std::endl;
  return out;
}
```

Universal reference is the only scenario where the template type deduction actually deduces a reference type, and if you pass an lvalue, `T` becomes an lvalue reference (in this case `X&`). So in fact no copy happens in the body of the function as only references come into play. When instantiated, the function looks like this:

```cpp
X& Foo(X& t) {
  X& out{ t };
  std::cout << "out = " << out.s_ << std::endl;
  return out;
}
```

It takes a reference and returns a reference, no extra instance was created, merely references are bound to your `x` variable. Later on, when a non-reference value `y` is assigned to a reference bound to `x` (after return from the function):

```cpp
auto y = Foo(x);
```

..it actually requires another instance to come into existence and the copy constructor is called.

Answer (score 2):

With perfect forwarding, `T` is `X&`. The corrected form of `Bar` would be:

```cpp
X& Bar(X& x) {
  X& out{x};
  std::cout << "out = " << out.s_ << std::endl;
  return out;
}
```

(Similar things would happen if it was a const lvalue and it was `const X&`)

So the copy is being made when initializing `auto y = Foo(x);`, where the type of `y` is `X` (not `X&`, since you don't have `decltype(auto) y` or `auto& y` or `auto&& y`), after you output `out = name`

Replace `T` with `std::remove_cvref_t<T>` or `auto` where appropriate to get your desired behaviour:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::remove_cvref_t<T> Foo(T&& t) {
  std::remove_cvref_t<T> out{std::forward<T>(t)};
  std::cout << "out = " << out.s_ << std::endl;
  return out;
}
```